# SQL - Asignar un valor en una operacion de recuperacion de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

En una consulta simple, tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
SELECT * FROM [SAMX].[dbo].[REPORTE_ESTADO_CUENTA_GLOBAL] where intencion_id=1657 ORDER BY intencion_id,fecha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Requiero llenar la columna cuenta con un '0' o un '1' dependiendo de si la consulta contiene un cargo inicial del contrato de la siguiente manera: 
- si no lo contiene, cuenta debe ser '0'
- si lo contiene, debe revisar el estatus de ese registro
- si el estatus es 'C', cuenta debe seguir siendo '0'
- si el estatus es '', cuenta debe ser '1', y todos los registros a partir de aquí, cuenta debe ser '1'

Intenté usando una variable, pero no puedo combinar un `SELECT` de asignación de valor con uno de obtención de datos.

```
DECLARE @var1 int;
select @var1=0;  
SELECT  @var1=(CASE tipomovimiento WHEN 'Cargo Inicial del Contrato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ,@var1 AS cuenta,[fecha],[tipomovimiento],[abono],[cargo],[estatus],[intencion_id] FROM REPORTE_ESTADO_CUENTA_GLOBAL  where intencion_id=1657 ORDER BY intencion_id,fecha
```

Me podrían sugerir alguna solución?

El resultado esperado seria asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes agregar el resultado esperado para la columna cuenta en los datos de ejemplo que pusiste?

Comment: si pruebas de la siguiente manera `SELECT  (CASE tipomovimiento WHEN 'Cargo Inicial del Contrato' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cuenta,[fecha],[tipomovimiento],[abono],[cargo],[estatus],[intencion_id] FROM REPORTE_ESTADO_CUENTA_GLOBAL  where intencion_id=1657 ORDER BY intencion_id,fecha`

Comment: agregue la imagen como resultado esperado, en tu propuesta, pondría '1' solo al renglón donde estuviese la descripción 'Cargo  Inicial del Contrato', no a los siguientes consecutivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, un `LEFT JOIN` y una expresión de `CASE` deberían funcionar:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN B.intencion_id IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN A.estatus = 'C' THEN 0
            WHEN A.estatus = '' THEN 1
        END Cuenta,
        A.fecha,
        A.tipomovimiento,
        A.abono,
        A.cargo,
        A.estatus,
        A.intencion_id
FROM [SAMX].[dbo].[REPORTE_ESTADO_CUENTA_GLOBAL] A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM [SAMX].[dbo].[REPORTE_ESTADO_CUENTA_GLOBAL]
            WHERE tipomovimiento = 'Cargo Inicial del Contrato') B
    ON A.intencion_id = B.intencion_id
    AND A.fecha >= B.fecha
WHERE A.intencion_id = 1657 
ORDER BY A.intencion_id,fecha;
```

Comment: no se me había ocurrido compararlo de esta manera, muchas gracias, resuelve por completo la problemática.